# element form: missing } after function body

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this code:

```
<form name=formSearch action="javascript:SMPStartSearch()//">
  <input type="text" name=txtSearch class="search">
  &nbsp;
  <input name=send type=submit value="Search">
</form>
<script src="search.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

When I validate using validator.w3.org I get the error message:

> Error: Bad value javascript:SMPStartSearch() // for attribute action on element form: missing } after function body

Where?

Comment: Use  `action="" onsubmit="SMPStartSearch(); return false"` or no inline JS

Answer (score 0):

Instaed of

```
<form name=formSearch action="javascript:SMPStartSearch()//">
```

use

```
<form name=formSearch action="javascript:SMPStartSearch();">
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks. Sorted. Why didn't I think of that?!